# pydoc injecting python submodules content to main module

Tags: python, boost-python, pydoc

I have a module `dlprim`

```
dlprim/
  __init__.py
  netconfig.py
  _pydlprim.so
```

its `__init__.py` incldes:

```
from ._pydlprim import *
from .netconfig import *
```

where `._pydlprim` is boost.pythom module and `.netconfig` is submodule.

If I generate a documentation with `pydoc -w dlprim` - it does not include classes from `_pydlprim` and `netconfig.py` so in order to generate them all I need to run `pydoc -w dlprim dlprim.netconfig dlprim._pydlprim`

But I get 3 separate files each in different namespace I want all of the classes to be found under `dlprim` module and namespace in pydoc.

How can I do it, or is there an alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the names of those re-exported items in `__all__`.

```
from ._pydlprim import *
from .netconfig import *

def _all_of(mod):
    try:
        yield from mod.__all__
        return
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    for item in dir(mod):
        if not item.startswith('_'):
            yield item

__all__ = [*_all_of(_pydlprim), *_all_of(netconfig)]
```